# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'from_user'

Tags: python, aiogram, sqlite3, aiogram-3.x

Всем привет! Помогите исправить ошибку пожалуйста, гпт и бард не смогли

```py
async def register(Message, callback, universe_selected):
    user_id = callback.from_user.id
    username = callback.from_user.username
    status = 'active'
    extrapass = 'inactive'
    universe = universe_selected
    money = 100
    cards = 0
    team = 0
    try:
        con = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
        cursor = con.cursor()

        sqlite_insert_query = """INSERT INTO users
        (id, username, status, extrapass, money, cards, team, universe)
        VALUES
        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);"""

        data_to_insert = (user_id, username, status, extrapass, money, cards, team, universe)
        count = cursor.execute(sqlite_insert_query, data_to_insert)
        con.commit()
        print('[DEBUG]: SUCCESS')
        cursor.close()
    except sqlite3.Error as error:
        print("Ошибка при работе с SQLite", error)
    finally:
        if con:
            con.close()
            print("Соединение с SQLite закрыто")
    await menu_universe_dev(callback)

# Основная команда /start
@dp.message(F.text == '/start')
async def cmd_start(message: Message):
    id_to_check = message.from_user.id
    con = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
    cursor = con.cursor()
    id_to_check = message.from_user.id
    cursor.execute("select id, universe from users where id=?", (id_to_check,))
    db_ckecker = cursor.fetchone()
    if db_ckecker is not None:
        id_to_compare = db_ckecker[0]
        universe_to_compare = db_ckecker[1]
    else:
        id_to_compare = 1
        universe_to_compare = None
        universe_to_check = 0
    if id_to_compare != id_to_check or None:
        await message.answer('Добро пожаловать!\n\nПожалуйста, выберите вселенную, чтобы продолжить!', reply_markup=kb.universe_selection)
    if id_to_compare == id_to_check:
        if universe_to_compare == 0: #DEV Вселенная, вырезать/залочить при релизе!
            await message.delete()
            await message.answer('Нажмите "Автовход", чтобы продолжить!\n\nТекущая вселенная: DEV', reply_markup=kb.login)
            con.close()
        elif universe_to_compare == 1: #Игровые вселенные
            pass
        else:
            con.close()
            await message.answer('Упс, не удалось найти ранее выбранную вами вселенную ') #Ошибка, если ТГ айди в БД есть, а айди юниверса нет
            await message.answer('Добро пожаловать!\n\nПожалуйста, выберите вселенную, чтобы продолжить!', reply_markup=kb.universe_selection)

@dp.callback_query(F.data == 'dev_universe_1')
async def cb_menu_and_universe_selection(CallbackQuery):
    callback = CallbackQuery
    print(CallbackQuery)
    universe_selected = 0
    print(universe_selected)
    await register(callback, universe_selected, Message)
```

Написал только нужный код*

Ошибка:

```
   user_id = callback.from_user.id
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'from_user'
```

Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте заменить `callback.from_user.id` на `callback.message.from_user.id`. Должно сработать